# Auto Save Email as Draft like gmail feature Using Asp.Net MVC jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, email

I have written code for sending email in that i have included Save as Draft like in gmail feature. But now i tried simply saving when the Save as Draft button clicked. But i need Once "Save as Draft" button clicked still user need to change the body of email content means it will automatically save the remaining boby of the content using Asp.Net MVC and Jquery.

Comment: You did not provide enough detail to receive a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `setInterval` Javascript function to automatically run code every 30 seconds, like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //Do autosave
}, 30000);  //30,000 milliseconds
```

Comment: Better to chain calls to setTimeout. That way the server won't get clogged if requests end up taking more than 30,000ms to complete.

Answer (score 1):

To implement the google approach you will need to use ajax to post the draft email content back to the server. Using an interval as suggested by SLaks to initiate your ajax call is a good approach. You will then need a MVC controller that processes / stores the data. Every new email will need an ID of some sort. In psuedo code:

1. interval gets triggered.
2. use ajax to post the form data (including the id).
3. mvc action processes the post by updating the data in the datastore.
4. when the email is finally sent, clear it from the datastore.

This will allow you to display drafts to the user from where ever they login. If you only want the user to see their drafts, then you will need to tie the datastore to your membership database.